# Why is method overloading not working in this C# program?

Tags: c#, overloading

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Derived obj = new Derived();
            int i = 10;
            obj.Foo(i);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    class Base
    {
        public virtual void  Foo(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base:Foo()");
        }
    }
    class Derived:Base
    {
        public override void Foo(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo(int)");
        }
        public void Foo(object i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo(object)");
        }
    }
}
```

output of the program according to me should be Foo(int) but output is coming as  Foo(object) please help me in understanding the diffrence in output

Comment: "Close is better than far away." The compiler prefers the method first declared in the derived class, which is the object overload. For more: http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/#more-1806

Answer (score 7):

Good question, I can reproduce your results.  If one takes a look at the C# [specifications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) one will find the following snippets:

**7.5.3 Overload resolution**

> For example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not
>   include methods marked override (§7.4), and methods in a base class
>   are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable
>   (§7.6.5.1).

**7.4 Member Lookup**

> Otherwise, the set consists of all accessible (§3.5) members named N
>   in T, including inherited members and the accessible members named N
>   in object. If T is a constructed type, the set of members is obtained
>   by substituting type arguments as described in §10.3.2. **Members that
>   include an override modifier are excluded from the set.**

**7.6.5.1 Method invocations**

> The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from
>   the most derived types: For each method C.F in the set, where C is the
>   type in which the method F is declared, **all methods declared in a base
>   type of C are removed from the set.** Furthermore, if C is a class type
>   other than object, all methods declared in an interface type are
>   removed from the set.

Sounds  a bit complicated?  Even the C# designers seem to think so and put in the 'helpful' note:

**7.6.5.1 Method invocations**

> The intuitive effect of the resolution rules described above is as
>   follows: *To locate the particular method* invoked by a method
>   invocation, start with the type indicated by the method invocation and
>   *proceed up the inheritance chain until at least **one applicable,
>   accessible, non-override method declaration** is found*. Then perform
>   type inference and overload resolution on the set of applicable,
>   accessible, non-override methods declared in that type and invoke the
>   method thus selected. If no method was found, try instead to process
>   the invocation as an extension method invocation.

If we take a look at your derived class, we see two possible methods for C# to use:

```
 A) public override void Foo(int i) 
 B) public void Foo(object i)
```

Let's use that last checklist!

**Applicability -** Both A and B are applicable -(both are void, both are named 'Foo' and both can accept an integer value).
**Accessibility -** Both A and B are accessible (public)
**Not Overridden -** Only B is not overridden.

But wait you might say!  A is more specific than B!

Correct, but that consideration is only made *after* we've disregarded option A.  As Eric Lippert (one of the designers) puts it [Closer is always better than farther away.](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/#more-1806)  (Thanks Anthony Pegram)

**Addendum**

There is always [the 'new' keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx):

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public new void Foo(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(int)");
    }

    public void Foo(object i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(object)");
    }
}
```

Though the specifics of that best left for another question!

Answer (score 0):

The simple datatype int descends from object. You are overriding the function and also overloading the parameter list. Since the function name is the same with a different signature the compiler allows this. For simple objects, I image one copy of the parameter signature in the most basic form is stored in the method table.