# Function overloads in C# are they a good idea?

Tags: c#

So i have a situation where i need different amounts of arguments for a function depending on the end result i desire.

I am new to C# and have heard about overloading the function which is not something i have seen before (i started in JavaScript).

But it looks bit dirty, like not a good practice to do even though it does work. Is it generally not a good idea to use overloaded functions, i could probably do an alternative with more work but overloads do make life easier.

It just feels very uncomfortable having more than one method with the same name. Are these considered standard features and acceptable code practice ? Or could it lead to some messy problems in the future that my inexperience does not know about yet and thus i should avoid it ?

Comment: You can pass arbitrary number of parameters to a method in javascript. No offence,  I personally think overload is much saver than doing that

Comment: A method with many parameters is not a good practice, methods may have the maximum of 3 parameters, if you need more, It suggests you to create a class. But overloading methods is a good practice, so you will  have a method that do what you want, and the others just set the default values to the parameters.

Comment: @Henrique a maxium of 3? I've never heard of that rule before.

Comment: @WDUK you can see at the chapter of Methods in the book Clean Code (Robert C Martin)

Comment: I mean i have methods that take more than 3 argument to crunch some math. Making an entire class for it seems a bit of a stretch. I think i would only make a class if it was becoming unreadable.

Comment: @WDUK - I think Henrique means "a maximum of 3 parameters" as a guideline and nothing to do with it being a hard limit.

Comment: The title of the question is opinion based ("good") - but the other questions - is this a standard (i.e. does Microsoft recommend this sometimes) and what sorts of problems arise (i.e. what are the pitfalls of this feature) are answerable without introducing much opinion... Maybe WDUK in the future have exactly 1 question mark somewhere in your question, make it clear that's the question and make sure it's not opinion-based - I think it's a good question and people coming from languages JavaScript like you would have it...

Comment: Thanks i guess most people see the title and report it. I am still getting used to the right way to word questions - still new-ish to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public void MyMethod(int a, object b)
    {
    }
}
```

If someone else calls your class like this:

```
new MyClass().MyMethod(1, 1);
```

And then in a future version of your assembly you add an innocent overload:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public void MyMethod(int a, object b)
    {
    }

    public void MyMethod(object a, int b)
    {
    }
}
```

That someone else's code will not compile against the new assembly.

You are correct that method overloading can introduce problems... however it is not always problematic.

Suppose the simple case - you have a method that operates on one `Type` - `T`.  If you are tempted to add a method overload to handle a second `Type` `U`, consider what interfaces and base classes `T` and `U` might have in common (including `T` or `U` extending one another).  If there is a common `Type` consider making that the argument type at design time (if that's specific enough).  If not, then you may need a method overload.  A good contrived example might be a method that returns the square of a number.  There is no common abstraction for `Type`'s that have an `*` operator (which you can write your own in C#).  So you'd have to make (2) methods to handle an `int` and a `double`:

```
public int SquareMe(int x) { return x * x; }
public double SquareMe(double x) { return x * x; }
```

If, however, you found yourself wanting to make a method operating on `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and `T[]`, you may be better off writing the method to accept an `IEnumerable<T>` (and just calling `ToArray()` on it immediately to prevent the `IEnumerable` from expanding multiple times if your code needs it multiple times - if you're just `foreach`'ing it once, there's no need to expand it) this way you're left with only (1) method to write tests for.  Every method, particularly on publicly consumed API's is more to maintain, document, test, automate, etc.  Simpler is usually better (but complexity has its place, too). It's difficult to give an algorithm for design of API's (if there was an existing algorithm for such a thing, we could just have the design generated as the output from some hypothetical program, yes?)

When it comes to designing classes and interfaces for public consumption you should be very careful about method overloading (and your entire API, in general - method overloading introducing subtle breaking changes is just one thing to think about - almost any change could be a breaking change).  If your API used by everyone, such as Microsoft, all changes to API's have to be very well thought-out and have minimum to 0 breaking changes.

If it's for "internal" use (and you can detect compilation breaks at build time) then if the compiler's happy, method overloading shouldn't be too big of a deal in and of itself.  That being said - someone might call a different overload by accident because of what C# will choose.  It's probably more important to have explicit method names (Microsoft recommends spelling things out in C#, generally) that intuitively (i.e. subjectively) match the content of what the method does than the concern of overloading.

Like other things, this language features is a trade off between being explicit and implicit and whether or not it's a good idea varies on the situation; method overloading can be both used and abused.  In general try to learn the existing practices, patterns and culture of a new language before developing your own style on things so that you can take advantage of everyone's successes and failures before you.  Method overloading definitely has its place in C#.

Comment: Basically this boils down to beware of overloads where one of the arguments is object.

Comment: I am glad i read this answer as i just so happened to have an argument that is an object!

Comment: @Joshua It's not just limited to `object` - because `Int32` can be promoted(?) to an `object` it works - if you had classes A and B such that A subclassed B you could make an analogous problem (I didn't demonstrate that because that was more complex).  You can have ambiguity in default parameter values (which store the default value in the caller counter-intuitively) and variable length parameter lists as well to worry about.

Comment: Almost all other cases I encounter a and b turn out to be types with no common base other than object. I know you could construct the scenario otherwise, but in my mind something's gone terribly wrong long before you get there.

Comment: @WDUK Having an `object` is not the problem, in and of itself.  If you're used to languages like JavaScript you may be tempted to make types in C# `object` or `dynamic` - you should be explicit, generally speaking, when possible, in C# so you catch as much as possible at compile-time and not run-time.  Sometimes you *want* to take in an `object` (i.e. serialization of a POCO to a `string`).  I would recommend studying some C#.  I used this site myself when I started ~5 years ago to learn most of the syntax, but I already knew Java: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson01

Comment: To be fair though I did end up constructing the analogous pattern once. It turned out it didn't matter which one was called. If I recall correctly I had an algorithm that required one of its two inputs to be an IDictionary<> and the other one to be a IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>  and the reversed overload just called the other one.

Comment: @Joshua An `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` so the compiler would have known what to do if you only had the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` overload...

Comment: Sigh. It's funcname(IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) and funcname(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>). It's ambiguous if you pass 2 IDictionary objects.

Comment: @Joshua I misread you - my bad!

Comment: Mentioning the `object` situation is an excellent information nugget. It is so... .Net 1. :-) +1

Comment: @Joshua I guess I wonder why you couldn't just have funcname(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>) and maybe call ToDictionary() on one if you need to for performance reasons so the IEnumerable isn't expanded each time...

Comment: The question was if method overloading is good practise (it is), this answer shows one potential ambiguity... rather than addressing the actual question.

Comment: @NPSF3000 I opened with an example of how method overloading can go wrong to confirm OP's suspicions of a language feature going awry.  The thesis of my answer was that it is not in and of itself a bad idea (in C#) and that its usage is a tool that can be used properly or improperly.  If you only understood the code example and not the explanation I provided around it I could see how you thought I didn't answer the questions of OP.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Method overloading isn't a 'language feature going awry' but a valuable feature that can on occasion have some subtle issues.  You spend a lot of time cautioning against using it, but no effort to explain *when* to use it.  Contrary to "Microsoft recommends spelling things out" they explicitly state "Use method overloading to provide different methods that do semantically the same thing."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxfyae0c(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @NPSF3000 Knowing when to use it and when not to use is a big question, too big for this format on this site - I never said it was always misused.  I gave OP a link to learn basic C# syntax and recommended OP to study C# considering the question that was being asked.  Now you bring up a good point that I didn't give a concrete example of when to use it, even though I implied clearly such uses exist, so I could improve my answer and add that... thanks.

Comment: "so I could improve my answer and add that... thanks. "  I can agree with that, a very rough read indicates you warn/caution about using method overloading 7ish times in the language you use, but maybe once say there's a benefit to using it (suggesting it's 'implicit').  Method overloading is a pretty simple concept I'd recommend to any beginner, and while there are subtle issues they are *subtle* and unlikely to cause major issues.  Even the example 'breaking change' isn't something a beginner usually has to worry about.  Pro's vs cons.

Comment: @NPSF3000 My intent was not to dissuade the use of method overloading - if it came across that way to many people then I did a poor job communicating my idea.  I tried to give a more balanced answer with my edit this time.  Let know if you can think of any further improvements.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared much better.  Note the "ToArray()" advice is bad.  A method consuming IEnumerable should not call ToArray unless it must by necessity.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Thanks! Well I said so that the `IEnumerable` isn't expanded multiple times; implicitly if the `IEnumerable` is expensive to compute (consider `IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>`) then you may want to make sure it's pulled into memory only once. Of course the disadvantage is you have the whole thing in memory, now, but you shouldn't be operating on an `IEnumerable` unless you have some idea how many elements could be in it or and whether or not it's pulling from the database, etc.  I edited it to make that more clear - if you were confused, maybe I wasn't clear for others, either.

Comment: "then you may want to make sure it's pulled into memory only once."  That is a decision of the method that passes the IEnumerable, not the method that consumes it.  For the space of these comments consier that I pass you A)  A very large array B)  An infinite enumerable

Comment: A) I wouldn't recommend RAM as the storage to do computations on a sufficiently large array... You probably don't need it in all RAM to begin with and if you did now your process has large minimum RAM requirements.
B) I probably wouldn't have an infinite `IEnumerable` - I would maybe use a different API if I was streaming something and wanted it to run forever and do something on each frame.

Comment: My assumption stated earlier was that you should have some idea what the `IEnumerable` you receive represents and code is not required to handle cases that don't make sense in "the real world" - it's a waste of your investor's money to design programs that handle huge data sets if they don't ever come up/it's not a requirement.

Comment: If you're writing something that doesn't specify the generic type argument, I see your point - that's a collections utility; it should work on any collection and not have to expand the `IEnumerable`, but I was assuming it was bound to a specific type like `IEnumerable<Customer>` - how many customer's will you have?  There's only 7 billion or so people today, but you probably won't be that successful, so even if it was the entire dataset, it wouldn't be that much probably - why do you need to pull that in memory in the first place?

Comment: Also the fact that [`IEnumerable<T>.Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919303(v=vs.90).aspx) exists implies your B) case is the exception not the general rule.  Methods don't need to handle all possible inputs that the compiler doesn't complain about - not even utility methods - that's *silly* - it's up to the method writer to implicitly or explicitly declare what inputs make sense - in this case why would you call Count on an infinite `IEnumerable`?  Oh no Linq methods must be awful because they don't operate on infinite `IEnumerable`'s....?

Comment: @Words Like Jared to put it bluntly, you don't know what you're talking about.  IEnumerable.Count does not call ToArray, IEnumerable.Count does work with large or Infinite collections (albeit calling it on never ending collection is pointless with the default implementation).  As a general rule the caller should decide to call ToArray, not the callee. Do not create lame arguments about how many customers one would have to defend poor code.  "You probably don't need it in all RAM to begin with"  You do realize that's what ToArray does?  Forces it all into memory (every time you call it!)

Comment: ...I never said it did?  `IEnumerable.Count` returns an `int`.  Why don't you try putting putting something with more than 2,147,483,647 elements and see what happens.  The API mentions an `OverflowException` which is what happens when *the number of elements in source is larger than MaxValue.*  Like I said - good API == documented, tested, versioned, and lots of other things.  good API != I didn't get a compiler error, so I shouldn't get a run-time error - if I did that means the API is bad.  No it means you can't read and understand.  (Judging from your responses, I think that's the case.)

Comment: Unless you have some constructive feedback for my answer to the question I think these comments are fruitless at this point because you're not addressing my points.  Either I'm having a hard time explaining them, you're having a hard time understanding them or you're trolling (and I'm bad at discerning trolls).

Comment: @ Words Like Jared you clearly state in your answer that a method accepting a IEnumerable should immediately call ToArray on that IEnumerable.  That is terrible practice.  You arguments around Count() simply show that A you don't know how count works and B you don't know how LINQ in general works.  Either do your homework or stop putting incorrect advice into irrelevant answers.

Comment: "should" != "you may be better off".  Also you missed the context/presuppositions (i.e. you already have a method accepting an `[]` that does the same thing and you're planning on needing to expand the `IEnumerable` more than once...). .....

Comment: " you're planning on needing to expand the IEnumerable more than once"  ToArray may make this far slower (even in  a bad scenario crash the application), not faster.  Again learn LINQ before giving terrible advice.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense if you interpret me to mean "You can write code so that it's /always/ safe to call ToArray on an IEnumerable" is what you think I'm saying.  I'm saying "You can write code so it's /sometimes/ safe/better to call ToArray on an IEnumerable." If the elements themselves are hard to compute (i.e. a database query with expensive aggregations) and they're small in total (small number of rows), it's fine.  You should not write non-library level software unless you know roughly how big you're operating on. Universal quantifier vs. Existential quantifier.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Obviously if you're writing library level software (i.e. IEnumerable with a generic) you would not make such assumptions on the cardinality, although maybe you'd make one that it's computable by an integer (Say Count()).  If I could make a suggestion it's better to try to figure out what the other person is meaning (like I did - I noticed your statements added up if I changed my quantifier from existential to universal).  Most people are relatively intelligent when it comes to things they've thought through - they usually are just operating on a different experience set or vocabulary

Comment: There are not many things you run into that need software that exceed an integer by much.  This is not because these things do not exist mathematically - it's because the people driving the need for software do not themselves comprehend such things.  I love math and cardinalities of infinity - it's awesome - but those things do not generally have a place in enterprise software.  You may live in a more research-oriented or academic environment (which is equally valid) but then are unable to understand the world does not operate using infinities because they get by with a finite approximation.

Comment: "If the elements themselves are hard to compute (i.e. a database query with expensive aggregations) and they're small in total (small number of rows), it's fine."   And how can the Callee method know whether or not the passed in IEnumerable meets that criteria?

Comment: @NPSF3000 So if I'm dealing with a typed non generic IEnumerable - is it abosolute or relative?  Suppose I have a concept of "patient" - I might want to view all "patients" which is absolute (and probably arbitrarily large - all people - billions potentially).  However data limited to a particular patient, say their medical visits, then each person lives 100 years and has 365 days of data, then I have 36,500 records, roughly to consider.  If you try to build computers to handle infinity you'll spend a lot of time.  If you make more assumptions (and build a way to improve your software

Comment: when your assumptions are wrong or change you have a process to upgrade your software, including versioning and migrating.  Sure you can write stuff to handle infinities, but most problems that need coding for don't need that (which is why languages don't usually have good processing on infinities, although if you needed that you'd pick a good DSL or cloud computing or AI, etc. to do the job).

Comment: That being said the "most problems don't need proper treatment of infinity" is based on my experience, which may be totally different than yours - you could have a different view based on the problems you've had to solve - such as lots of academic or research problems or framework-level or language-level or something where it's more abstract and you can't make as many assumptions on how it will be used.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared just FYI I've build software that handles patients, and if my team did what you did I'd have corrected it.  The problem you have though is still the one I identified earlier:  "And how can the Callee method know whether or not the passed in IEnumerable meets that criteria?"  Talk to me all you want about how small the dataset is, how does the *callee* method know that?  Why would you add an entirely unnecessary step when as a callee you do not know whether or not that step is appropriate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109938/discussion-between-words-like-jared-and-npsf3000).

Answer (score 5):

> Function overloads.

Named actually *method* overloading. C# does not have a direct distinction to *methods* which return a value and those that don't. Hence *method*.

> But it looks bit dirty

It is a key component to the language which is a common practice and definitely not frowned upon.

> like not a good practice to do even though it does work.

The idea is to provide different variants for a consumer. One consumer may only have X type to use while only Y type is offered. By offering more, the library, and/or instance is more flexible. Plus it lessons failure points by having the consumer convert data to get it into the method.

> (i started in JavaScript).

Don't try to program in the *style* of language which one is accustomed to. Use the specific features of any new language as designed. By trying to do Java in C# or Ruby in C# is foolish. All languages have their design points...program to the language, not to a style of programming.

> just feels very uncomfortable having more than one method with the same name.

Coming from a language which is not *type* safe, that is an understandable reaction. But keep in mind that the compiler is enforcing *safety* so that widget X is only matched with widget X; it is a true feature and not a gimmick.

Frankly when I see code which does not provide multiple overloads, I view it as either laziness of the developer or some god awful time crunch, hence rushed code.

Don't go overboard...simply provide enough overloads to make the class useable by a majority of consumers.

> Or could it lead to some messy problems in the future

If one is not consistent, possibly yes.

So be consistent in the placement of the variables. If an `int` starts the method, the other method should also start with that same `int`; if offered. Don't mix the order.

Comment: "The idea is to provide different variants for a consumer. One consumer may only have X type to use while only Y type is offered." Exactly - especially if `X` and `Y` do not inherit from each other or have a common interface/base class that could be used instead.  "Don't try to program in the style of language which one is accustomed to...." Exactly.

Everything in this answer is good! +1

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a situation that would be made easier by a core feature of the language you are using... and you're concerned about that?  I wouldn't worry too much.

It might be idea to make an attempt and once you're happy with it take it over to codereview.stackexchange.com to get some feedback.

Comment: So it is a C# feature by design not like some trickery that people exploit based around how the code happens to interpret method calls. This was what i was unsure of.

Comment: @WDUK it's certainly a design consideration.  I recently answered a quetion about very specific situation, and the design docs showed that even this was carefully consisdered and specified:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407947/why-is-method-overloading-not-working-in-this-c-sharp-program/36410132#36410132

Answer (score 0):

If the reason for varying signatures is because 'the end result you desire' varies then that's a case for having different functions.

Overloading is helpful when you have a number of optional parameters. If you have five optional parameters it's less obvious what will happen if you specify some but not others. If you create overloads then you can provide different versions of the function with required parameters. Perhaps behind the scenes they can all call a private method with optional parameters, but that remains hidden from public use.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use an optional parameter?

```
void Foo (int op = 42)
{

if (x!=42)
 //do something
else

}
int x = 33;
Foo();
Foo(x);
```